# Split Array Clean up

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Sorry about the Title. Couldn't think of anything else.

I have this formula written with the help I received here:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("+",IFERROR(INDEX(TO_TEXT(SPLIT({D$3:D$50;L$3:L$50},"|")),,1)),""),"+")))))
```

Which works fine. The only issue I have is when the range {D$3:D$50;L$3:L$50} is totally blank it returns a load of +++ and I can't work out what to wrap in an "if" statement to stop this, without causing the array results to offset. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=if(and(isblank(D$3:D$50),isblank(L$3:L$50)),"",  
ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("+",IFERROR(INDEX(TO_TEXT(SPLIT({D$3:D$50;L$3:L$50},"|")),,1)),""),"+")))))
)
```

The middle line is the same as you already have.